# Can a Worker Service be called and/or used inside an existing ASPNET.Core web project?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, backgroundworker

I've been reading and learing about the new Worker Service features provided in .Net Core 3.0. I have been using this link from Microsoft: [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

What I don't understand is this, can these worker service concepts be introduced into an existing ASPNET Web Project, like a Razor Pages site? Or must you create a new project and then deploy that project as a service using whatever mechanism the host OS proivdes for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can host any number of hosted services (`IHostedService`) within ASP.NET Core applications. With version 3, ASP.NET Core uses the generic host (`Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`) which is the framework that is hosting these hosted services when the application starts. In fact, the ASP.NET Core web application is an `IHostedService` itself.

To add additional hosted services to your ASP.NET Core application, just register additional hosted services with your service collection, e.g. within the Startup’s `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
```

That service will then launch together with the ASP.NET Core web server when the application runs.

The Worker SDK that is mentioned in the documentation is actually a subset of the Web SDK that you are using with ASP.NET Core application. `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker` is basically `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` without the web-specific stuff like Razor compilation and `wwwroot` folder stuff. It basically sets up automatic file globbing e.g. for the `appsettings.json` and does some other useful things that the core `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` does not have.

Ultimately this means, that when you are using the Web SDK, then you already have everything the Worker SDK offers. So you do not need to specify the Worker SDK just to host additional background services.

Comment: Thank you so much, poke. I'm going to ask another question about how to launch a background process using the Web SDK