# Is .NET TPL using a queue under the hood?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library

I am new to .NET and I am wondering if TPL (Task Parallel Library) is using a Queue under the hood for the tasks that you start ?

So can I "queue" or start as many Tasks I want and .NET will handle this? Why would I need a BlockingQueue etc. then?

I am asking this because I need a WebApi (.NET Core) that accepts a message and puts it to a queue and then do some processing with it. If I am right then I would not need a Queue or so, but just queue a Task right?

So in short: Can I just "queue" Tasks with TPL or do I need a BlockingQueue or so to process my incoming messages via the API?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think you need to manually "queue" tasks?

Comment: @Fildor So, I receive a message via an Rest API. Can I just create a Task and do the processing OR do I need to put that message to, lets say a BlockingQueue and have a Thread processing this Queue?

Comment: @Fildor I am just wondering if you can use TPL as a queue or do I need to create a BlockingQueue, queue my message and then another Thread is processing that queue

Comment: By starting a task, it gets queued to the thread pool. Once a Thread is available, it will execute  the task. So you can just start as many tasks as you like. You don’t need to queue them manually. That's what the ThreadPool is designed for.

Comment: You are too far already. Read up on how .NET Core handles requests. If you need asyncronous handling, [TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) will have you covered most of the time. _If you have "long running" processing_ going on, add this info to your question, because that is a whole different story.

Comment: What kind of tasks do you want to execute here? Are these CPU-bound tasks? Then it’s probably better not to put each of those into the thread pool but to work them off from a limited number of worker threads.

Comment: @Fildor Ok, lets say it is long-running, can I not just use TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning ?

Comment: @poke It does some parsing, contact other APIs, accesses a database, sends email

Comment: Especially in a .NET Core WebApi, where should I create a BlockingQueue to put the messages in and how can I handle them ?

Comment: @bbrinck If you want some general background worker within an ASP.NET Core app, I’d suggest using a hosted service that works off queued jobs. I explain that in detail with an example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60249560/216074).

Comment: @bbrink Well, it depends if you need to give feedback or not. Assuming the "tasks" are fire&forget, you could queue them and have them processed by some worker service as poke suggests. If you need to give feedback to the caller, it will be a "little" bit more complicated.

Comment: @Fildor Sure, but assuming that I do not need to give feedback, then what should I use as a queuing system? A BackgroundService/HostedService or something like HangFire?

Comment: I don't think you need a queue for a fire & forget thing. You can simply call Task.Run or something.

Comment: Cannot tell you what to use. I don't know anything about your system and requirements. Are you running in the cloud? Is there load balancing? How much load do you expect? How much peek load do you expect? Is this a proof of concept? Is this production code? Do you need to weed out dupes? ... Much to consider here. You could even go for some "Serverless" solution e.g. with Azure Functions ... sky is the limit.

Comment: @LeisenChang Ok, but if I would like to have a queue, what should I use ?

Comment: @Fildor Well, I am learning .NET and this is more of a general question, because this scenario is bothering me since a while. Scenario: API to receive a message, put to a queue, process it. No load balancing, Load maybe 10.000 messages a day, and peak may be 50 messages/second

Comment: You probably have to answer the first question Fildor asked "Why do you think you need to manually "queue" tasks?". IMO 99% of time you don't need to use queue to manage your tasks if you're using TPL.

Comment: OK, then. Have a look at the link in poke's comment and give it a shot. But you know what: If you originally thought TPL would be a solution, try it out. Maybe you fail. Failing is learning. Just be aware that there may be a point where you should consider a different approach :)

Comment: @LeisenChang I think we have worked this one out: OP wants to process long running "tasks" (not necessarily `Task`s) without feedback to the caller ("fire&forget"). So it actually _does_ make sense to have a queue of some kind.

Comment: @bbrink What you should consider: 10.000/day means about 7/minute. If you expect a peek of 50/s (which is _a lot_ higher than expected avg) you need to make sure that a) the queue has enough capacity and b) the processor(s) can actually process fast enough to flatten out peeks. Or maybe processors can be scaled (additional workers etc).

Comment: I just want to say TPL is usually good enough to deal with long running fire & forget tasks. Unless you have tested it and found it's infeasible to this case, you don't really have to invent another queue mechanism.

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Fire and forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). The correct solution is not the easy one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you shouldn't. Task uses a thread pool under the hood.

First, it's unconstrained, so you have no control how many are queued/started, means you have little to no control how many start, run or are waiting to be processed. If the tasks are running longer, it can happen that the background tasks use all the available threads in the pool and the requests have to wait. With a queue and worker processes you have more control, i.e. 1 queue and 2 background processes. Then you know at any point, no more than 2 background tasks are processed at the same time.

Second, more important, it doesn't make your application process data faster. You get lower latency (faster response) to the caller, but the background tasks still take the same time to process. And latency is only then lower when there is no (or low) load.
As the load goes up, you may get longer responses (much longer than it takes to process the task) again because too many background tasks (see first point) are running, taking all the CPU and threads, making requests wait.

Comment: Thank you. Okay and how would you create a Queue and a Task/Thread that processes that queue in a .NET Core WebApi ?

Answer (score -3):

Does the call need to wait for the task to finish? If not, then it's best to queue the tasks and process them somewhere in a background thread. If you have to wait for the task to finish, then await is you friend!

Comment: _"If you have to wait for the task to finish, then await is you friend!"_ Not in all cases. If there is some heavy **long running** process, the request may end up in time outs. So, for that you'd need a different pattern.

Comment: No, I do not need to await the task. The API message should be processed in the background. I would use Hangfire, but I do not see the point there, if I am right to say that TPL is a queue, so I could just queue them using TPL.